# Prevent Script From Automatically Launching at Startup

Tags: powershell

Some time ago, in preparation for syncing AD with Microsoft Azure, we ran a vendor provided Powershell script that now launches every time someone logs onto the server. The problem is that before completing the Powershell script in question, the vendor provided a new process (an executable instead that did what this script did and more). We did not let the script complete and part of it's process was to launch automatically after a reboot so that the remainder of the steps within it could be completed.

I've answered 'No' to the two prompts I get when it launches hoping it will close out (and it does until I log in again). I've also tried typing 'exit' hoping it would no longer auto-launch. I have also used Task Manager to end the task. No matter how I exit the script for the current session, it comes back. How can I kill this script? It's not saved to the computer anywhere. It's not in the startup folder or anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several locations to look for. See: [Windows Automatic Startup Locations](https://www.ghacks.net/2016/06/04/windows-automatic-startup-locations/).

Common ones to take a look at are:

## Startup folders

### Current User

```
%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

### All Users

```
%programdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
```

## Task Scheduler

```
Task Scheduler (Local) -> Task Scheduler Library
```

## Registry Startup

### Run keys (individual user)

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run (only on 64-bit systems)
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Run
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce (runs the program/command only once, clears it as soon as it is run)
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx (runs the program/command only once, clears it as soon as execution completes)
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce
```

### Run keys (machine, all users)

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run (only on 64-bit systems)
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce (runs the program/command only once, clears it as soon as it is run)
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx (runs the program/command only once, clears it as soon as execution completes)
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce
```

## Group Policy

```
Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Logon > Run these programs at user logon
User Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Logon > Run these programs at user logon
```

Comment: Thanks. Finally found it at:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run